# HOW TO IGNORE DUPLICATES with laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, foreach, duplicates

I'm working on reactJs with laravel CHAT. I want to display juste the last message from the sender. But I usually get all his messages. I tried lot of attempts But I didn't get the solution yet. this is my last attempt:

```
 $types= chat::select('id','senderId')->where('userId', $id)->get();
   foreach ($types as $chats) {
            $chats->chat = chat::select('id','unseenMsgs', 'senderId')->where('senderId', $chats->senderId)  
        
            ->get();
           foreach ($chats->chat as $child){ 
                $child->lastMessage = chat::select('userId','message', 'time', 'senderId')     
                ->where('id', $child->id)        
                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->skip(0)->take(1)
                ->get();
        }
        }
    return ['chatsContacts' => $types];
```

The userId is the receiver one and senderId is the one who send the message. At first query I tried to get all the messages that are sent to the reciever. The question is how to ignore the duplication and get juste the last message from the sender one. and Thanks in advance for your help
Ps: I'm using An MVP and the reponse should be like this:
[this picture is for the response in the MVP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMVE5.png)

That's why in my server side I should create an api which return exactly this response

Comment: Can you try adding `groupBy('userId')`

Comment: @aceraven777 where !

Comment: To where the duplicate is happening

Comment: @aceraven777 still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to recreate the issue with the amount of information provided.
From what I understand about the problem description, following seems like a possible solution:

```
$latestChats = chat::select('id', 'userId', 'message', 'time', 'senderId')
    ->where('userId', $id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->unique('senderId');

return ['chatsContacts' => $latestChats];
```

This should give you a collection containing the last messages sent by every `senderId` to the specified `userId`.

If this does not resolve your issue please provide further information.

1. What does the table look like?
2. What is the exact format you're looking for in `chatContacts` ?

Comment: I updated my question thank you now I ignore the duplication for the sender Id but for the last message it didn't work correctly. The same message is showing for all the senders even if this isn't coming from him

Comment: @syrinebh sorry for the late response. Could you please provide more details on the tables and their relationships? From the looks of it there's another entity involved (`chatContact`).